# How to merge two different languages in .Net?

Tags: visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mixing C# & VB In The Same Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278024/mixing-c-sharp-vb-in-the-same-project)

Is it possible to write two applications using different .Net languages (For example C# and Visual Basic) and combine the two into a single program in Visual Studio?

I want to write two parts of one program in two different languages and merge them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to clarify what exactly you are after, but the .Net languages are more or less interchangeable. You could write one DLL or component in C#, and another in Vb.Net, and then use both in a parent application which could be in either language (or something different entirely).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add two project in a solution, A project C# library and another project with VB, Then reference a project to another, Test it and enjoy on .Net Technology!