# Can I use an asp.net master page in vb for an application written in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a website (asp.net 4) with 49 pages.  The website is in **vb**.

But I added a forum (and called it "knowledgbase"), so it's like ... company.com/knowledgebase/ ... I configured the forum as a separate application in IIS7, and it's written in **c#**.

Is it possible to use one of my vb master pages in the c# forum?  Or would I have to create an entirely separate c# master page?

**Edit:**

Basically, in the knowledgebase/default.aspx file, there's this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false"   
Inherits="YAF.ForumPageBase" culture="auto" uiculture="auto"  %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="YAF" Assembly="YAF" Namespace="YAF" %>
<script runat="server">
```

I tried doing this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" 
Inherits="YAF.ForumPageBase" culture="auto" uiculture="auto" 
MasterPageFile="~/homepage.Master"  %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="YAF" Assembly="YAF" Namespace="YAF" %>
<script runat="server">
```

But of course ... the page language says "c#" and the master page is written in vb.  So the result was this (as expected):

```
Server Error in '/knowledgebase' Application.
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service 
this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your 
source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The 'masterpagefile' attribute is not supported by the 
'register' directive.
```

Comment: Yes you can but you need to copy VB master page into `forum` webapp.

Comment: what have you tried so far? i think you can as long as it is on the same project

Comment: I'll update the question to say what I've tried ...

Comment: Based on the error message, are you sure you put the `MasterPageFile` attribute in the `Page` directive?  It's saying that you can't have that attribute in the `Register` directive.  Are we missing some additional information?

Comment: Let me update it again, to be more accurate ... Thanks for trying to help, @TLS!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278024/mixing-c-sharp-vb-in-the-same-project

Comment: Thank you ... I read through the info on the link you gave me, Sicko.  But I think my case is different.  All I'm trying to do is apply a master page, not "mix code" page by page.  And as I mentioned, the /knowledgebase/ folder is designated as a separate application in IIS7.  So I'm still looking into this.  Thank you for taking the time to respond!