# Converting an ASP.NET Website that has C# and VB to a Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET Website project that I have converted to a Web Application. I converted the App_Code which has sub directories for vb and cs it renamed to the folder to Old_App_Code. Now the C# code will not compile, none of the syntax is recognized and several hundred errors show in the error list.

I know its possible to have both languages in a website project but how do I compile both in a web app project? or do I have to convert all the C# to VB?

Comment: What happens if you take the Old_App_Code out of your project somewhere else?

Answer (score 7):

To run C# and VB together you can do some [changes in web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a15ebt6c%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) such as;

```
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="%ASSEMBLY_VERSION%"/>
        </compiler>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="%ASSEMBLY_VERSION%"/>
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
```

and

```
<compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="VB">
<codeSubDirectories>
                <add directoryName="CS_Code"/>
            </codeSubDirectories>
        </compilation>
```

for the rest you you use this walktrough

https://stackoverflow.com/a/735062/929902