# How can I integrate C# libraries into Visual Basic?

Tags: c#, vb.net, libraries

There are some libraries written in C# that I would like to use in Visual Basic, but I can't find any tutorials or anything giving me any clues as to how it is done.  I have compiled (I think) the library, but I have looked everywhere (including the project properties) for a solution with no success.

Comment: In your project, add the library (project or binary) as a reference. The former is preferred, as it will allow you to debug the library code.

Comment: I think adding the dlls will be enough.

Comment: How do I add the dll files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are in the same solution, just "Add Reference" and select the C# project. If not, compile them into a .dll and "Add Reference" -> select the path to it.

You should then be able to 'Include' / 'Import' methods, classes and objects from the C# projects / libraries.

[image: Add Reference Dialog]

Answer (score 3):

If you have compiled your C# code into a DLL, you should be able to reference it in a VB.NET project as you would any other DLL. Include your DLL somewhere in your project's folder structure (typically in a "lib" folder), then do the following:

- Open your C# project in Visual Studio.
- Right click on "References" in the Solution Explorer and click on "Add Reference."
- Select the "Browse" tab, then browse to - and select - the desired DLL.

For more information on adding and removing references, visit [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can just add it to your VB.Net project as reference and then use it. Once code is compiled (VB.Net or c#) its in IL(intermediate language) so there is no difference. Look at the example I gave in the answer of following question. I have done exactly what you are asking for.

[Can C# compiler compile a VB.Net code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826999/does-asp-net-use-same-compiler-to-compile-vb-net-and-c/20827041#20827041)

You can find out how to add reference by going to below URL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: If you are looking on how to add reference you can go to the msdn link I provided but if you want to understand how c# and vb.net compiler works go to the first (SO) link.