# How to Using VB.NET classes together in the App_Code folder for C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Hi I have a webservice project using C# project. Currently I have a vb file that I want to use. I put it on a folder name ,VBCode, inside the App_Code. I also follow the [Using C# and VB.NET classes together in the App_Code folder](https://virendradugar.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/using-c-and-vb-net-classes-together-in-the-app_code-folder/). I added the namespace and modified the webconfig. However when I complied it that I got a lot of error such as ";expecting". Is it possible to have vb file in C# project.

```
 <codeSubDirectories>       
    <add directoryName="VBCode"/>
  </codeSubDirectories>
```

Comment: the easiest way to mix C# and VB is through class libraries.   Simply make a VB class library and put your VB code in that.  Your C# class can then reference that lib

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the answer is yes and you are doing the configuration in the right way. however this an old tricky code. I suggested migrating the code to C#.

Anyway, you can find more information on these answers associated with the same question here in Stackoverflow.

[Mixing C# & VB In The Same Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278024/mixing-c-sharp-vb-in-the-same-project)