# C# and VB.net in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, model-view-controller

I jumped in an asp.net mvc application developed in vb.net, but I am much more experienced in c#.
So I ask myself, if there is any way to program new features in c# as an assembly ( i.e. the login-controller, -model and -view) and use it in these application?

I know, mixing both in the same file is not possible.

thanks a lot 
Peter

Comment: I don't think you can do this - see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278024/mixing-c-sharp-vb-in-the-same-project

Comment: You can add new assemblies in any other .NET language, but not in the very same unless you r rewrite the existing code base.

Comment: The web application itself will need to be done in VB if that's what language you selected when you created it. You can create libraries using C# for a lot of the functionality though, e.g. a service layer and the data model.